# PHP Cookies Won't Delete!

Tags: php, cookies

I have a site with an option to "stay logged in." When the option is checked, I set cookies for one month like so:

```
$expire = time()+60*60*24*30;
setcookie("user_ID", $userid, $expire);
setcookie("u", $username, $expire);
etc.
```

Then I have a logout script to kill the cookies, setting the value to null and the expire date one hour in the past.

```
$expire2 = time()-60*60;
foreach ($_COOKIE as $c_id => $c_value)
{
    setcookie($c_id, NULL, $expire2);
}
```

When I run the logout script, Firebug says this:

**Set-Cookie**
userID=deleted; expires=Tue, 02-Feb-2010 16:43:15 GMT
u=deleted; expires=Tue, 02-Feb-2010 16:43:15 GMT

But when I go back to the main or any other page, I'm still logged in! The only time I set the cookie is when I run the login script, so why won't they die? Could it have anything to do with local time being behind GMT?

Comment: Are you using $_SESSION based cookies for maintaining authentication?

Comment: How does your authentication work? And have you checked what happened with your cookies?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Never mind. As with most mistakes I make, this one was pretty stupid. I was setting path cookies, and my logout script was in a different directory than the login script. I've set them to domain cookies and they're working now.